# How to do a count query that groups by distinct product

Tags: mysql

Ok so i have this query

```
SELECT *
FROM configure_system
WHERE EstimateID='EDB95PY0Z2'  AND StepID=1
```

which will return the following 8 rows...i need a query that only returns all the distinct productID and the total price and the quantity of them ...so for example

i want something like this

```
ProductID   ProductPrice TotalPrice quantity
2           575          1175       2
3           839          1678       2
9           1349         4047       3
12          1699         1699       2
```

I tried using the distinct query and count but have not been successful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT   ProductID                            ,
         ProductPrice                         ,
         COUNT(*) * ProductPrice AS TotalPrice,
         COUNT(*)                AS quantity
FROM     configure_system
WHERE    EstimateID='EDB95PY0Z2'
AND      StepID    =1
GROUP BY ProductID,
         ProductPrice
```

Comment: is it correct to use where clause in aggregate query in mysql? it's illegal in Sql server and oracle too as far as I know

Comment: @Jani: Using a `WHERE` clause with `GROUP BY` definitely isn't a problem in any of these products. The problem occurs if you try and use an aggregate in the where clause. e.g. `WHERE COUNT(*) =1`. This is illegal and needs to go in the `having` clause.

Comment: Yes, you're right pal, having is used to filter columns appeared in group by clause

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at the "GROUP BY" clause, and "aggregate functions"

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ProductID,ProductPrice,SUM(ProductPrice),COUNT(*)
FROM configure_system
WHERE EstimateID='EDB95PY0Z2'  AND StepID=1
GROUP BY ProductID,ProductPrice
```

Answer (score 1):

It will be sth like this

```
SELECT productId
      ,count(*)
      ,count(*)*price
  FROM [Table_1]
  GROUP BY productId,Price
  HAVING productId = 'blabla'
```